# Error storing data DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'persist:root' exceeded the quota

Tags: image, redux, storage, sentry

I have this error everytime I uploaded big file image. The website is working fine, however on my console on the website showing this error. I am using Redux and Sentry. Do you think this is a possible BUG on Sentry or Redux?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using redux-persist and putting that image into the redux store. LocalStorage is capped somewhere around 10MB so it's pretty easy to reach that.

Generally, I'd recommend you to put only normal data into your redux store, not something like images - it is not really suited for that.

As an intermediate fix, you could try to use the `blacklist` feature of redux-persist to exclude that image from persisting to localStorage, but in the long run you should really not put images into your redux store.